# How to compile mod_wsgi 4.5.3 with Python3.5.2 under centos7, Apache/2.4.6

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-3.5

I tried ./configure for mod_wsgi 4.5.3 like below:

./configure --with-python=/opt/Python352/bin

Where /opt/Python352 folder is installed with python3.5.2.

However in CentOS 7 the "configure" always builds the mod_wsgi with binary "python"(corresponding to python2.75) not with binary "python3" or "python3.5".

Requirement is to get the .so file, the latest for mod_wsgi 4.5.3, compiled using python3.5.2 and load this in Apache/2.4.6 under CentOS 7.

Thanks.

Comment: AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/7.0.7 mod_wsgi/4.5.3 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations        --Is the log from httpd. ****what I want is mod_wsgi/4.5.3 Python/3.5.2 configured****Aliasing python to python3.5 in the ~/bashrc did not help as known

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an exact dump of what I use for CentOS 7.2. You can probably do without a lot of the pre-reqs, but I figured I'd include them since many are handy to have:

```
echo 'Python 3.5.2 is not installed, installing Python 3 pre-requisites...'
yum -y groupinstall development

echo 'Installing extra packages for Python...'
yum -y install zlib-devel openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel python-devel openssl-devel libffi-devel openssl-perl libjpeg-turbo-devel zlib-devel giflib ncurses-devel gdbm-devel xz-devel tkinter readline-devel tk tk-devel

echo 'Installing Python 3.5.2...'
wget -q 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz'
tar -xzf 'Python-3.5.2.tgz'
cd ./Python-3.5.2
CXX=g++ ./configure --enable-shared
make

echo 'Moving to alternate location to keep system Python version intact...'
make altinstall
cd ..
rm Python-3.5.2.tgz
rm -rf ./Python-3.5.2
ln -fs /usr/local/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.5
echo "/usr/local/lib/python3.5" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python35.conf
echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python35.conf
ldconfig

echo 'Now, install mod_wsgi...'
wget -q "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.4.21.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.4.21.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.4.21
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
make
make install
```

I couldn't see an obvious problem with your question given the information, but figured a complete working example would help.

Comment: Thanks for the help with most comprehensive details! This where I struggled: I did not know simply installing latest python will not have --enable-shared applied. Since I installed without --enable-shared and that too into /usr/local...I had issues while installing mod_wsgi...with right version of Python.  Also I didn't knew about ./configure --with-python= python_bin_path.

Comment: Just to make it obvious as to the problem, the ``--with-python`` option to ``configure`` for mod_wsgi is supposed to be the full path to the ``python`` binary, not the ``bin`` directory containing it as was originally being used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much @FlipperPA your dump saved so much time of me and let me grasp a better understanding on this.