# Django app not being served with Python3.5 and httpd

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, server

I have a Django app hosted on:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Oct 19 2017 20:39:16
```

here's my `django.conf` file:

```
    Alias /static /home/faizan/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/faizan/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/faizan/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/faizan/myproject:/home/faizan/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/faizan/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

My application was working when I had python 2.7 installed in my virtual environment and had `django.conf` like this:

```
Alias /static /home/faizan/myproject/static
<Directory /home/faizan/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/faizan/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/faizan/myproject:/home/faizan/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/faizan/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache2 with mod_wsgi,the mod_wsgi binary has to be compiled against one Python version only and only one instance of a compiled mod_wsgi module can be loaded into Apache at a time.

You install mod_wsgi with python2.7,if now you system defalut python is python 3.5,you can reinstall mod_wsgi by(for ubuntu,i don't know how to reinstall for centos,but all you need to do is reinstall mod_wsgi with the python(must be same install) with you virtualenv use):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

If you system defalut python is not python3.5,download mod_wsgi from [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases),and manual compilation and installation with python you used in virtualenv(also for ubuntu):

```
    tar xvfz mod_wsgi-X.Y.tar.gz
    cd mod_wsgi-X.Y/ 
    sudo ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.5 
    sudo make 
    sudo make install 

    sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load 
    LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so # write this to wsgi.load

    sudo a2enmod wsgi
    sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this on my Ubuntu system and it says `checking Apache version... ./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found` when doing `sudo ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.5`

Comment: After searching a lot, I come to know that this is common issue with python 3 and mod-wsgi. The alternative fix to this is suggested following instructions [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi/4.4.8#id1) .

Comment: And this works with `python manage.py runmodwsgi` but is this suitable solution for live server? Does this work similarly as we define `WSGIDaemonProcess` in an Apache virtual host?

Comment: If you don't restart apache2,it will use the before conf.You can config everything well and restart it on live server.I think it's not like WSGIDaemonProcess ,the mod_wsgi must be reinstall and  compilation 
 with right python version when your change you django project' python version.

Comment: And i think this may helpful when you use dev ubuntu system. 
        ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs 
  --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python   
     link:http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#configuring-the-source-code

Comment: `/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs: No such file or directory`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256266/how-to-compile-mod-wsgi-4-5-3-with-python3-5-2-under-centos7-apache-2-4-6/38287125) may help. cd /usr to find apache and apxs,see where it's